# Scala Join Arrays and Reduce on Value

Tags: arrays, scala, reduce

I have two Arrays of Key/Value Pairs  Array[(String, Int)] that I want to join, but only return the minimum value when there's a match on the key.

```
val a = Array(("personA", 1), ("personB", 4), ("personC", 5))
val b = Array(("personC", 4), ("personA", 2))
```

Goal: `c = Array((personA, 1), (personC, 4))`

```
val c = a.join(b).collect()
```

results in: `c = Array((personA, (1, 2)), (personC, (5, 4)))`

I've tried to achieve this using the join method but am having difficulties reducing the values after they have been joined into a single array:  `Array[(String, (Int, Int))]`.

Comment: It occurred to me that `a` and `b` might be _Apache Spark_ `PairRDD` collections, and not `Array`s (since `join` is not a _Scala_ `Array` function). I updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if this works for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
val a = Array(("personA", 1), ("personB", 4), ("personC", 5))
val b = Array(("personC", 4), ("personA", 2))
val bMap = b.toMap
val cMap = a.toMap.filterKeys(bMap.contains).map {
  case(k, v) => k -> Math.min(v, bMap(k))
}
val c = cMap.toArray
```

The `toMap` method converts the `Array[(String, Int)]` into a `Map[String, Int]`; `filterKeys` is then used to retain only the keys (strings) in `a.toMap` that are also in `b.toMap`. The `map` operation then chooses the minimum value of the two available values for each key, and creates a new map associating each key with that minimum value. Finally, we convert the resulting map back to an `Array[(String, Int)]` using `toArray`.

**UPDATED**

BTW: I'm not sure where you get the `Array.join` method from: `Array` doesn't have such a method, so `a.join(b)` doesn't work for me. However, I suspect that `a` and `b` might be *Apache Spark* `PairRDD` collections (or something similar). If that's the case, then you can join `a` and `b`, then map the values to the minimum of each pair (a `reduce` operation is not what you want) as follows:

```scala
a.join(b).mapValues(v => Math.min(v._1, v._2)).collect
```

`collect` converts the result into an `Array[(String, Int)]` as you require.

Comment: Thank you Mike.  Yes, it is indeed a PairRDD which does allow for the join statement.  Is it possible to do a reduction of the two Int's in an object after the join as a separate statement?

Comment: @SMC A `reduce` operation is applied to an entire collection, resulting in a single value (or an error, if the collection is empty). If you apply `reduce` to an `RDD`, you'll get a single value—and you need an `Array`. If you're wondering whether you can apply `reduce` to a _tuple_, then no, you can't. In the general case, _tuples_ are not homogeneous (for example, you could have a _tuple_ of a `String` and an `Int`), and a `reduce` can only be performed on homogeneous elements. In your case, you're morphing a `[(String, (Int, Int))]` value to a `[(String, Int)]`, which is a `map` operation.

Comment: @SMC `mapValues` is a `PairRDD` optimization that is applied on just the _value_ of each pair. It's simpler and more efficient than a `map` on both the _key_ and the _value_. It also ensures that no expensive repartitioning takes place.

Comment: Mike Allen - Thank you for the explanation.  It's very helpful.